# How to dynamically set a variable across all roles by calling a java class

Tags: ansible

I want to assign a value to dictionary based on the output of a java class. I am using shell module to call the java class. I tried writing tasks in vars/main.yml but ansible doesn't execute tasks written in vars/main.yml. Below is my vars/main.yml

```
---
tasks:
  - name:  java command 1
    shell: "command"
    register: var1

  - name:  java command 2
    shell: "command"
    register: var2

my_dictionary:
  key1: "{{ var1 }}"
  key2: "{{ var2 }}"
```

On accessing `my_dictionary.key1` or `my_dictionary.key2`, ansible is considering them undefined. How to execute the tasks and assign the values to dictionary.

Comment: When using the shell module, the output will be stored in `var1.stdout or var1. stdout_lines`. Depends on the use case, which one you want to use.

Comment: The issue is to make the task execute before assigning the values to the dictionary.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question, ansible will not execute tasks defined in vars/main.yml

Answer (score 2):

put the 2 tasks in the `tasks/main.yml`, then use the [set_fact module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html?highlight=set_fact) to create the `my_dictionary` variable with the registered vars `var1` and `var2`.

example of `set_fact` module:

```
- set_fact:
    one_fact: something
    other_fact: "{{ local_var * 2 }}"
    cacheable: true
```

Comment: But, if I want to use `my_dictionary` across several executions? `my_dictionary` set by set_fact will only be available to the subsequent plays.

Comment: how is it that you are doing a task (meaning you expect the var to change) but expect it to be "available to the subsequent plays"? Do you mean "available to the following roles"?

Comment: @user3086551 oh, for subsequent plays to other hosts, then not sure this is possible. Why not re-run whenever needed? if they are "costly" tasks, maybe you could save the output to file, and read it on the subsequent plays that you will need that output?

Comment: @tedder42 Yes, I mean the variable should be available to the following roles. That's why I was setting the variable in vars/main.yml and using the variables by importing the vars files `vars_files`

Comment: You can set a variable in the top of a play. It'll propagate to the roles that follow. You can use "facts" or "pre_tasks". I use the latter quite a bit.